# How will I filter out my own clicks in Google Analytics?

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I searched on google support but couldn't find a way to filter out internal traffic, can anyone help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A filter by IP maybe a solution. Other solution could be set a cookie and avoid tracking if cookie is present. There are other solutions like these, but I think the more simple solution is to use an [AdBlocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblocker-ultimate/ohahllgiabjaoigichmmfljhkcfikeof?hl=en) extension for browser.